# Changes to Custom fields on Un-managed and Managed apps

Tags: unmanaged-package

1)  I have an un-managed package.  The subscriber has installed in into their sandbox and have added 30 fields to a custom object and page layout.  I’ve created a new version of the app and we want to install it.  Does the subscriber have to un-install the first version?  Will they lose their custom fields?  Can they preserve it for the new version?

2)  Similarly, If the same scenario exists with a Managed package, will upgrades wipe out the custom fields?  Will they have to un-install to install a new version?

Answer (score 0):

Unmanaged packages can't be upgraded. Upon install, conflicts can be automatically renamed. However, this means duplicate objects and fields will be created. In some cases, automatic rename may fail, so the old package would have to be manually fixed. No data is lost, but you'd have to migrate data. Basically, you'll have two versions installed side-by-side.

Managed package fields have a namespace that unmanaged fields will not. They won't conflict, but data will need to be migrated. The same is true for classes and other code that may exist.

Upgrading a managed package is never destructive. No data or fields will be lost as a result of upgrading a managed package to a new version.

Comment: #sfdcfox I added some fields to my test environment and un-install and reinstalled my un-managed package.  As expected, my test fields disappeared with the un-install of the object.  I understand I can add the fields again and migrate the saved data.  I suspect that's the solution.  About upgrading the managed package.  Will my new version overlay the old version and the additional fields and data will be preserved?

Comment: @Stan uninstalling may not be necessary. Try installing two versions and see what happens.

Comment: I have Betas of Version 1 (un-managed).  When I create a new Beta, the message is that I need to uninstall the current version of the app.  I just tried to create a new 'Version' and the help text says that the current version number will not increment until I upload it as managed-released.  I'm not ready to do that until we finish testing.  So, I don't believe installing 2 versions will work.  I welcome your input.

Comment: @Stan beta is still managed. You can't install the same beta twice. You also can't upgrade beta to release. So, your only choice will be backup, uninstall, install, and restore. Customers should not be given beta versions.

Comment: Thanks.  The customer is our beta site. So, when I load it as 'Managed' and the customer adds fields to the custom object, and I, then, publish an upgraded  version, my new version overlays the old version and the additional fields and data will be preserved...correct?

Comment: I just posted this question and thought you might have the answer:  'Can a subscriber Add actions to, or modify the actions of a workflow in an installed managed package?  Such as adding an OB message?